# Reading Binary file on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, binaryfiles, binaryreader

I want to read a binary file using BinaryReader, but I keep getting an exception:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(stream)) //EXCEPTION
            {

            }
        }
```

the "file.bin" has been set as a Content in the build action, but I keep getting this exception:

System.MethodAccessException was unhandled

Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.File.Open(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `File.Open` on Windows Phone 7 - you have to use [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

See the [`System.IO.IsolatedStorage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28VS.95%29.aspx) namespace for more details.

For example:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var stream = store.OpenFile("file.bin", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, for content built into the XAP, you should use [`Application.GetResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: but I need to read a file from the content of my xap file. can i access these files using IsolatedStroage?

Comment: @user836252: Ah, you should have said. No, those won't be in isolated storage. I believe you need [`Application.GetResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994(v=VS.95).aspx). See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045456/how-to-read-text-from-a-text-file-in-the-xap).

Comment: I've said it has been set as a content in the build action lol but thanks, it works using GetResourceStrea